# To preview html design template inside laravel framework

Tags: php, html, laravel, templates

I am creating a website that will contain free web design templates for downloading will be most likely same https://htmlcodex.com, the idea is to upload the full template .zip through the admin panel and then extract it in the laravel project public folder to be previewed as live demo for the template, but i do not know how to access the whole assets that will be inside the template and it should not be written with asset('css/style.css'), please help if you had done some project similar.

I already can display pages, but can not access the assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, by putting all templates folder in the laravel public path directly.